# beautifulsoup .get_text() is not specific enough for my HTML parsing

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

Given the HTML code below I want output just the text of the h1 but not the "Details about   ", which is the text of the span (which is encapsulated by the h1).

My current output gives:

```
Details about   New Men's Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black
```

I would like:

```
New Men's Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black
```

Here is the HTML I am working with

```
<h1 class="it-ttl" itemprop="name" id="itemTitle"><span class="g-hdn">Details about  &nbsp;</span>New Men&#039;s Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black</h1>
```

Here is my current code:

```
for line in soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'}):
    print line.get_text()
```

Note: I do not want to just truncate the string because I would like this code to have some re-usability.
What would be best is some code that crops out any text that is bounded by the span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Removing%20elements) to remove all `span` tags:

```
for line in soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'}):
    [s.extract() for s in line('span')]
print line.get_text()
# => New Men's Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to check if the string contains `html`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h1 class="it-ttl" itemprop="name" id="itemTitle"><span class="g-hdn">Details about  &nbsp;</span>New Men&#039;s Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black</h1>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for line in soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'}):
    for content in line.contents:
        if bool(BeautifulSoup(str(content), "html.parser").find()):
            continue

        print content
```

Another solution (which I prefer) is to check for instance of `bs4.element.Tag`:

```
import bs4

html = """<h1 class="it-ttl" itemprop="name" id="itemTitle"><span class="g-hdn">Details about  &nbsp;</span>New Men&#039;s Genuine Leather Bifold ID Credit Card Money Holder Wallet Black</h1>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for line in soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'}):
    for content in line.contents:
        if isinstance(content, bs4.element.Tag):
            continue

        print content
```