# How can I remove all different script tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I crawl a table from a web link and would like to rebuild a table by removing all script tags. Here are the source codes.

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
table = soup.find('table')

for row in table.find_all('tr') :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        #remove all different script tags
        #col.replace_with('') 
        #col.decompose()  
        #col.extract()
        col = col.contents
```

**How can I remove all different script tags?** Take the follow cell as an exampple, which includes the tag `a`, `br` and `td`.

```
<td><a href="http://www.irit.fr/SC">Signal et Communication</a>
<br/><a href="http://www.irit.fr/IRT">Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications</a>
</td>
```

My expected result is:

```
Signal et Communication
Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications
```

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462360/beautifulsoup-get-text-is-not-specific-enough-for-my-html-parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking about [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the
>   `get_text()` method. *It returns all the text in a document or beneath a
>   tag, as a single Unicode string*

```
td = soup.find("td")
td.get_text()
```

Note that [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) would return you `None` in this case since `td` has *multiple children*:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(u"""
... <td><a href="http://www.irit.fr/SC">Signal et Communication</a>
... <br/><a href="http://www.irit.fr/IRT">Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications</a>
... </td>
... """)
>>> 
>>> td = soup.td
>>> print td.string
None
>>> print td.get_text()
Signal et Communication
Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications
```

Comment: @SparkandShine it's basically the same (`text = property(get_text)`). You should though use `get_text()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling col.string. That will give you the text only.

Comment: What is the difference between `col.text` and `col.string`?

Comment: Here is the definition for text from the help documents for text:                             `text |      Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator.`        And for string                                                                                          `If this tag has a single string child, return value is that string.                 If this tag has no children, or more than one child, return value is None. If this tag has one child tag, return value is the 'string' attribute of the child tag, recursively.`

Comment: It doesn't work and return `None` because of multiple children as @alecxe said.